# Key in Python dataframe not being found

Tags: python-3.x

I'm practicing data analysis in Python, following a tutorial for the basic set up. I'm using a data frame of items sold in stores with categories including Item_Identifier and Item_Visibility; the same item can have a different visibility at each store. I'm trying to replace Item_Visibility of 0 with the average visibility of that item across all stores, but I'm getting a Key Error from my dataframe when the key should exist. 
sample of data:

```
import Pandas as pd
d = {'Item_Identifier':['FDA15', 'DRC01', 'FDN15', 'FDX07', 'FDX07'], 
'Item_Visibility':[0.016, 0.019, 0.017, 0, 0.02]}
data = pd.DataFram(data=d)
```

Item_Identifier    Item_Visibility
FDA15                      0.016 
DRC01                      0.019
FDN15                      0.017
FDX07                      0
FDX07                      0.02
 I made a pivot table using the code:

```
visibility_avg = data.pivot_table(values='Item_Visibility', 
index='Item_Identifier')
```

I then made a series of items with visibility 0

```
miss_bool = (data['Item_Visibility'] == 0)
```

I want to replace the 0 with the average visibility for that item in each store, so I used this code:

```
data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Visibility'] = data.loc[miss_bool,'Item_Identifier'].apply(lambda x: visibility_avg[x])
```

Then I get an error: KeyError: 'FDX07'. FDX07 is the identifier of the 4th item in data, the first item to have 0 visibility. My code is exactly the same as the tutorial, I'm using the same data, and I have the same libraries. I checked visibility_avg, and the keys are there. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please check out the guidelines on [how to ask a good quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without at least a sample of the data you're working with it will be very difficult to help.

Comment: I added some sample rows from my data. What is the best way to add samples from large data sets in the future?

Comment: Thanka for updating! In short, the best way to provide data is a way that lets someone looking at your question try your code and see what happens. So, something I can copy and paste, basically. I'm not at a computer right now so I can't try to reproduce your problem right now, but I will try later on.

Comment: I figured out the error. I needed to use .loc after visibility_avg.

Comment: If you have a solution it would be helpful for others if you post it as an answer! Then if someone else has the same problem they might find your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
lambda x: visibility_avg[x]
```

does not work because visibility_avg is a dataframe object. You need to use

```
lambda x: visibility_avg.loc[x]
```